# internet fragmentation and reassembly procedure

Tags: routes, network-programming, ip

I am currently reading the [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-2.1) of the IETF which explains the Internet Protocol thoroughly. At one place it talks about fragmentation and reassembly procedure based on network types. On researching further I came across a [research paper](http://www.ijcseonline.org/pub_paper/IJCSE-00234.pdf) the concept of MTU(Maximum Transmission Unit)  based fragmentation. I have two questions regarding this. Firstly, are fragmentation and reassembly costly procedures (which I hope they are as there are the creation of new datagrams and a lot of copying) and if they are then secondly, do the routing protocols take in consideration of a longer path with a greater RTT but also having a greater MTU such that less or no fragmentation is required if the datagrams proceed through them?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This site is for questions that directly involve programming.  Your question does not appear to be about programming, and therefore it is off-topic for Stackoverflow.  You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you ask this question on the https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ site instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly, are fragmentation and reassembly costly procedures (which I
>   hope they are as there are the creation of new datagrams and a lot of
>   copying)

That depends on what you consider "costly". But generally speaking, yeah. Fragmentation is something you want to avoid. It's wasteful and risky (if one fragment is lost, the entire packet is lost).

> secondly, do the routing protocols take in consideration of a longer
>   path with a greater RTT but also having a greater MTU such that less
>   or no fragmentation is required if the datagrams proceed through them?

No. Routers don't know the MTUs to different destinations. In practice, networks typically use a constant MTU of 1500 bytes, especially core networks. AFAIK the only places you might run into fragmentation in practice is at the edges of the network due to tunneling.

Comment: Then can i design a network layer protocol with heuristics in mind regarding congestion control, mtu and similar properties to effectively route a datagram in a more efficient way. I know it will require change in hardwares also but it's just hypothetical like if i design my own network above data link layer